# Expected [SRART_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using python to connect to elastic as following:

```
import urllib3

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

from elasticsearch.connection import create_ssl_context

import configparser

 

def get_es_session(es_user, es_password, es_host, es_port):

    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()

    ssl_context.check_hostname = False

    ssl_context.verify_mode = False

    es_session = Elasticsearch(

        hosts=[{'host': es_host, 'port': es_port}],

        scheme='https',

        ssl_context=ssl_context,

        http_auth=(es_user, es_password))


    return es_session
```

Then I'm trying to do the simplest search but getting the error above (**Expected [SRART_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]**):

```
es_session = get_es_session(es_user, es_password, es_host, es_port)

 

        #Init scroll by search

        res = es_session.search(index='digital-dashboard*',

            size=10000,

            from_=0,

            request_timeout=60,

            body=body,

            scroll='5m',

            )
```

The body I'm passing is minimal as it can get:

```
{

    "query": {

        "bool": {

            "filter": {

                "range": { "@timestamp": { "gt": "2021-07-12T13:28:54.297000" } }

             }

        }

     }

}
```

I even tried passing it as json and not a dictionary using json.dumps but nothing seems to work (I even passed empty brackets {} as body and still the same error).

Any ideas will be much much appreciated.

Here is the full trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/data/airflow/dags/digital_dashboard.py", line 172, in scroll_elastic
> res = es_session.search(index='digital-dashboard*',   File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py",
> > line 84, in _wrapped
> >         return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py",
> > line 1547, in search
> >         return self.transport.perform_request(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py",
> > line 351, in perform_request
> >         status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(   File
> > "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py",
> > line 261, in perform_request
> >         self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py",
> > line 181, in _raise_error
> >         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)( elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400,
> > 'parsing_exception', 'Expected [START_OBJECT] but found
> > [START_ARRAY]')   During handling of the above exception, another
> > exception occurred:
> >
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> > line 1138, in _run_raw_task
> >         self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)   File
> > "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> > line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
> >         result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> > line 1341, in _execute_task
> >         result = task_copy.execute(context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py",
> > line 117, in execute
> >         return_value = self.execute_callable()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py",
> > line 128, in execute_callable
> >         return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)   File "/data/airflow/dags/digital_dashboard.py", line 200, in
> > scroll_elastic
> >         raise Exception(error) Exception: error occurred while scrolling index: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Expected
> > [START_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]')

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace you are getting?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Which library do you use for connection? Is it this ES client?
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.3/index.html ?

How do you specify body - with or without outbound quotes?
Basically, body should be `{"query": {"match_all": {}}}`, not `"{"query": {"match_all": {}}}"`.

What's happening if you try the example from the documentation, e.g.
`es.search(index="your-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})` ?

Comment: yes elasticsearch==7.5.1. I even tried an older version 7.0.2 and still the same error.

I've also tried the example as mentioned body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}) - same error.